# Simple solution to get notification when certain events appear in Windows logs

Tags: security, windows-event-log

What is the most simple way to get a notification when specific events appear on Windows logs - anywhere on a windows network.

Answer (score 11):

Event Log Consolidator View, consolidate, and dismiss event logs and correlate issues across multiple systems

Tired of having to open Event Viewer and connect to each Windows system to see its event logs? Don’t have a centralized way to view events from multiple servers?

Download SolarWinds Event Log Consolidator to organize event logs from several Windows systems in one view. You can view, consolidate, and dismiss event logs, as well as correlate issues from one central location.

http://www.solarwinds.com/free-tools/event-log-consolidator

I use this everyday its actually very good.

Take a little IT know how.

And its free